# Unable to npm install webpack. code EPERM; errno -4048; syscall: 'unlink'

Tags: windows, npm, webpack

I'm unable to npm install -D webpack. I get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozlov\Desktop\cpay-ext\node_modules\fsevents\nod
e_modules\abbrev\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozlov\
Desktop\cpay-ext\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozl
ov\Desktop\cpay-ext\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\Ye
vgeny Kozlov\\Desktop\\cpay-ext\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\p
ackage.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Yevgeny Kozlov\\Desktop\\cpay-ext\\node_modules\\fs
events\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozlov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-31T
21_12_18_374Z-debug.log
```

It used to work normally. I would appreciate your help on what's going on with this machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed

```
C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozlov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\
C:\Users\Yevgeny Kozlov\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

folders and it has helped.